# Flutter Required Constructor Parsing With Two Different Type Possibilities

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I have a widget that has two constructors, where one of them has to be given (is required). I set up my widget like this:

```
class OneRmSetupView extends StatefulWidget {

  final Workout? workout;
  final Exercice? exercice;

  const OneRmSetupView.workout({Key? key, this.exercice, required this.workout}) : super(key: key);
  const OneRmSetupView.exercice({Key? key, required this.exercice, this.workout}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OneRmSetupViewState createState() => _OneRmSetupViewState();
}

class _OneRmSetupViewState extends State<OneRmSetupView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        ...
    );
  }
}
```

Now I have my routeGenerator that is set up like this:

```
class NavigationRouter {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      ...
      case oneRmSetupView:
        Workout? workout = settings.arguments as Workout?;
        Exercice? exercice = settings.arguments as Exercice?;
        
        if (exercice != null) {
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OneRmSetupView.exercice(exercice: exercice));
        }else if (workout != null) {
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OneRmSetupView.workout(workout: workout));
        }
      ...
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Scaffold(body: Text('Error')));
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a clean way of doing this? Is it okay for me to check the type by parsing it twice? Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `factory` constructor.

Something along this line:

```
class OneRmSetupView extends StatefulWidget {

  final Workout? workout;
  final Exercice? exercice;

  factory OneRmSetupView({Workout? workout, Exercice? exercice}) {
    if(exercice != null) return OneRmSetupView.exercice(exercice: exercice);
    if(workout!= null) return OneRmSetupView.workout(workout: workout);
    throw Exception('either excercice or workout must be not null');
  }

  const OneRmSetupView.workout({Key? key, this.exercice, required this.workout}) : super(key: key);
  const OneRmSetupView.exercice({Key? key, required this.exercice, this.workout}) : super(key: key);
```

Also, I thing it is **exercise** instead of exercice.

Comment: Thanks! How should I be calling it from my NavigationRouter?

Comment: No problem, dont forget the thumb :). Yes, you can. factory constructors are useful because they can decide what obj they will return. You can even have an abstract class factory constructor that decides to return other classes that implement/extend it

Comment: Do you know if I can check, while being inside the widget, whether the current widget is of type OneRmSetupView.workout or OneRmSetupView.exercice.

Comment: you must check if Exercise or Workout is null, OneRmSetupView.workout and OneRmSetupView.exercice are both OneRmSetupView for DArt, no difference between them